# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'' and problem with ssl certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ssl, pip

I have python 3.10 and installed opencv using pip command: pip install opencv-python
it installed fine, but when i try to import cv2, it gives the error:

```
PS C:\Users\Hemanth\Documents\opencv-basics> python -u "c:\Users\Hemanth\Documents\opencv-basics\opencv1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hemanth\Documents\opencv-basics\opencv1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I then tried to upgrade pip and reinstall opencv again,
The error when i try to upgrade pip is like this:

```
C:\Users\Hemanth>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (22.0.4)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

also, I don't have anaconda installed, I type in the pip commands in cmd.
Sorry for my poor English, can anyone please help me on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Aking that is not recommended anywhere. OpenCV has official packages on PyPI (pip). Anaconda/Conda/Conda-Forge is definitely not recommended.

Comment: your python installation seems broken severely. remove everything, reinstall. note that you have a python from MSYS2... make sure that's the only one. if you have one natively installed too, they will conflict.